# pyQt and QTextEdit: Why are some unicode characters are shown, others not?

Tags: python, unicode, pyqt, emoji, qtextedit

I try to display unicode text in a QTextEdit in pyQt.

It's Python 2.7 and PyQt4 on Mac OSX El Capitan.

I read through some Q&A about python, QString and unicode and came up with the following running example.

When run, it prints two unicode strings to the terminal and also shows them in a QTextEdit in its Main Window. 
The first string is ok (I copied it from a Q&A here on stackoverflow, actually I have no idea what it means in English...). 
I see all characters displayed correctly in my terminal as well as in the QTextEdit.

However, the emoticons of the second string are missing in the QTextEdit, although they are printed correctly in the terminal. In the QTextEdit there are two blanks in between the '---'. When I copy the blanks in the QTextEdit and paste them in a terminal, I see the emoticons. So it seems that the content is there, but not the graphical representation.

I set the font family to Monaco, as this is the font in my text terminal as well as in Eclipse, which I use for developing. Eclipse shows the emoticons correctly in its editor as well.

So I assumed that the Monaco font family would support the emoticons.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks for any help

Armin

Running example: Sorry for the length, this was copied in bits and pieces from existing code and a pyuic generated ui-class...

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
'''
# Importing the necessary Qt classes.
import sys
import re
import sip
import time

from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui  import *

from PyQt4 import QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(550, 350)
    self.ExitButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
    self.ExitButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 310, 100, 35))
    self.ExitButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ExitButton"))
    self.logView = QtGui.QTextEdit(Dialog)
    self.logView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 500, 280))
    self.logView.setReadOnly(False)
    self.logView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("logView"))

    self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
    Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
    self.ExitButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Exit", None))

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_Dialog):

    # quit
    def finish(self):
        quit()

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        # set up User Interface (widgets, layout...)
        self.setupUi(self)

        # custom slots connections
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ExitButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("released()"), self.finish) 

        self.logView.setFontFamily("Monaco")

        print("Zażółć gęślą jaźń")
        print("Xc--")

        t = QString.fromUtf8("---Zażółć gęślą jaźń---")
        self.logView.append(t)

        t = QString.fromUtf8("------")
        self.logView.append(t)


        print("family is " + self.logView.fontFamily())
        self.logView.append("family is " + self.logView.fontFamily())


# Main entry to program.  Sets up the main app and create a new window.
def main(argv):

    # create Qt application
    app = QApplication(argv,True)

    # create main window
    wnd = MainWindow() # classname
    wnd.show()

    # Connect signal for app finish
    app.connect(app, QtCore.SIGNAL("lastWindowClosed()"), app, QtCore.SLOT("quit()"))

    # Start the app up
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the output of `sys.maxunicode` for the python youy are using? If it's 65535 (rather than 1114111), you are using a *narrow* build of python, which does not support characters outside the [BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane).

The unicode code-point of "" is 128525, and "" 65535 is 128537, both of which are beyond 65535. In a narrow build, these will be represented as a surrogate pair, which presumably Qt does not know how to render.

Since [PEP-261](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0261/), it is possible to compile a wide build of python (by using the `--enable-unicode=ucs4` option) which has support for characters beyond the BMP. (For python > 3.3, only wide builds are possible).

Comment: Thank you very much. The output of  sys.maxunicode is indeed 65535, so this explains the behaviour of my code. I will have a look into how to get a wide build for my machine...

Comment: Ok, so I installed python3 (version 3.5.2) through homebrew, reinstalled sip&pyqt, updated Eclipse to use python3 and tried again. Now the output of sys.maxunicode is 1114111, but the behaviour of the running example is still the same, no emoticons in the QTextEdit, but still in Eclipse and terminal, still copying and pasting the two blanks from QTextEdit to the terminal shows the emoticons in the terminal. What else could I try?

Comment: @arminphys. You need to install a pyqt that has been compiled against a wide build of python.